# Electron's app.relaunch() loose stdio

Tags: electron, child-process, relaunch

Using

```
chokidar.watch(mainFile).on('change', () => {
   app.relaunch();
   app.exit(0);
});
```

I can have my Electron app auto-reload on source change. However since the main process is killed, I loose the terminal output which is necessary for debugging. Is there a way to use `app.relaunch()` retaining the `stdio` of the parent process?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: below I explain the setup I found as a decent workaround in 2016. Not sure if there is a better way in 2018.*

Reloading of my Electron app is handled in two parts:

### Rendered process

I use [electron-reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-reload) listening for changes only within the `renderer` folder:

```js
require("electron-reload")(path.join(__dirname, "/renderer"));
```

### Main process

Auto-reload handled "manually" via a Gulp script, as follows:

```js
let child = null;
let start = () => {
    // Was already running? Kill it and restart.
    if (child) child.kill();
    let env = process.env;
    env.NODE_ENV = "dev";
    child = proc.spawn(electron, ["./main/main.js"], { env: env });

    function print(data) {
        let str = data.toString().trim();
        if (str) gutil.log(str);
    }
    child.stdout.on("data", print);
    child.stderr.on("data", print);
};

// Run (dev mode with watch and autoreload)
gulp.task("dev", ["watch"], () => {
    start();
});

// Watch and move to dist on the fly.
// Hard reset if main process source changes.
gulp.task("watch", () => {
    // If ./renderer/**/*.js changes, electron-reload will handle reload of renderer process only.
    // If ./main/**/*.js changes, we kill the Electron process and start a new one.
    gulp.watch("./main/**/*.js", start);
});
```

Running the app with `gulp run dev` will start a watcher and kill/restart the entire application on file change.